# Can I move high amounts of data from a SQL server to Windows 8 app over TCP/IP?

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a proof of concept Point of Sale app for my store.  I was planning to use SQL express as the back end database and a Windows 8 app written in C# since their are so many solid devices that support it.  I now learned that the Windows 8 RT library does not support SQL client connections.

My thought is to make a dedicated desktop "server" app to provide the data to all the client POS and inventory management modules. Would this be possible communicating through TCP/IP and or XML or does the Windows 8 RT not even support this?  Any suggestions?  It's a Point of Sale so it will have a rather large amount of data to support?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use WCF in the service and the client would connect to an end Point and get the data from it.